# User input and finding multiples

Tags: java, eclipse, object, math

I'm new to **java** and I have an assignment asking to prompt user for a number between 2 and 10 and it is supposed to print out multiples of that number. It is also supposed to use a **for loop**.
I think I have the general idea with the **for loop** I'm just trying to figure out how to do the multiples. Any help is greatly appreciated! This is where I am so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter a number between 2 and 10:");

    for(int i = 2; i<= 100; i++){
        System.out.println(+ i);
    }
```

Comment: Please look again at the code you posted.  Does it have anything close to what your assignment is?

Comment: How many multiples are you supposed to print?

Comment: only the multiples of that number up to 100. So if you entered 9 it would be 9,,18,27,36...99

Answer (score 0):

A multiple of a number is that number times something.

So one multiple of i would be i * 13 (for example).

```
   of course you need to get number from the Scanner "in" object

   for (int i=2; i < 13; i++) {
     System.out.println(" Multiple (" + i + ") = " + i*number;
   }
```

Comment: Right, but it's saying it needs  every multiple so if they entered 3 it would print out 3, 6, 9, 12, etc.

Comment: What do you mean? I've gotten it to where it will print out the integers, I just can't figure out the function to get it to only print out the multiples.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest thinking about how you would go about doing the task mentally. When you're counting integers, you will add one each time (`i++`). When you're counting by, say threes, you will add three each time. You need to store your scanner's read value to a variable (don't try to read the scanner each time!) and adjust `i++` in your loop to add the number you read from the scanner instead.

Begin with:

```
int step = in.nextInt();
if(step >= 2 && step <=10){
    for(int i = 0; i <=100; ???){
        System.out.println(+ i);
    }
} else { 
    System.out.println("The step value was not between 2 and 10.");
```

}

I will leave you at this point as learning it for yourself is *far* more valuable than any Stack Overflow answer could ever be. If you are still stumped, I can guide you farther in the right direction.

Comment: And do *something* to ensure the number read is indeed between 2 and 10.

Comment: @PM77-1 Sorry about that, didn't notice at first.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. I just pointed that OP has one more detail to take care of.  You had no obligation to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that the user can only enter numbers between 2 and 10, and you will need to store the input for use in your for loop. For example:

```
int num = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
do
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a number between 2 and 10:")
    num = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
} while((num < 2) || (num > 10));
```

Followed by your for loop.